# Checking if a date picker value is less than todays date

Tags: c#

Trying to check when a user enters a date greater than todays date so I can throw up a message box to display an error and catch it. I've been trying the code below but it's saying I can't use operators to check. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
DateTime check;
bool checker = false;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dpDate.Text, out check) < DateTime.Now)
{
     checker = true;
}
```

Comment: What kind of application you are targeting and is your Date picker a simple TextBox or some control which has `DateTime` type field for value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime.TryParse` would return a bool indicating successful /unsuccessful parsing, modify your check like:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(dpDate.Text, out check) && check  < DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 3):

`TryParse` returns a bool value indicating if parsing was succesful or not and you cannot compare that to a date time. You should be doing this instead

```
DateTime check;
bool checker = false;
bool valid = DateTime.TryParse(dpDate.Text, out check);
if (valid && (check < DateTime.Now))
{
    checker = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `boolean` value.

So in your if statement you try to compare a `boolean` value (`true` or `false`) with a `DateTime`. You can't do that.

You should compare first your `check` and `DateTime.Now` with [`<`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5wecxwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then you can use [`&&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (conditional-AND) with result of `DateTime.TryParse` as Habib *[mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20433337/447156)*.

Since `<` operator has higher precedence than `&&` operator, you don't have to use any brackets.